# Music app won't allow me to transfer an MP3 from iTunes to my iPhone, says "Media may be damaged"

Tags: itunes, audio, music, error, mp3

I have an MP3 file I'd like to move onto my phone from my Windows PC. I've imported it into iTunes and played it there, where it works just fine. I tried choosing "Add to Device...my iPhone" in the menu and...nothing happens. No error message, no warning tone, nothing.

I then tried converting the song within iTunes to .AAC format and copying the resulting file across, but still nothing happens. I've found through trial and error that I first need to delete the original file from iTunes, re-import it, convert it to .AAC and then choose "Add to Device...my iPhone", and then the transfer will actually take place.

Except it doesn't- the .AAC file transfers to my phone (minus the album art, strangely), but when I try to play it in the Music app I get the first actual error message I've seen, which is "Cannot Open, This media may be damaged".

I've transferred many songs through iTunes before, usually without difficulty. The only thing I can think of with this particular file is that it's much longer than a typical song, but again I've transferred long tracks before without issue.

Has anyone else ever run into this situation, and if so did you find a solution? I'd really like to know more about what "this media might be damaged" could more specifically be referring to. Is there something fundamental I'm missing here?

[Here's the link](https://dubhed.blogspot.com/2021/12/bad-santa-iv-2021.html) to the source file if anyone wants to try themselves. For what it's worth, I'm running iTunes 12.12.2.2 on a Windows 10 laptop with the latest updates, transferring to an iPhone 8 Plus using iOS 15.2 with 17.85 GB available.